# php foreach() with a class array

Tags: php, class, foreach

I need some help. I have a working class and I can use a foreach() to display the public variables:

```
class MyClass {
     public $a;
     public $b;
     function __construct($aX,$bX){
          $this->a = $aX;
          $this->b = $bX;
     }
}

$class = new MyClass(3,5);
foreach($class as $key => $value) {
     print "$key => $value</br>\n";
}
```

produces:

```
a => 3
b => 5
```

Now my problem arises when I want to have an array of MyClass:

```
class MyClass
{
    public $a;
    public $b;
    function __construct($aX,$bX){
        $this->a = $aX;
        $this->b = $bX;
    }
}

$class = array(
     "odd"=>new MyClass(3,5), 
     "even"=>new MyClass(2,4)
     );
foreach($class as $key => $value) {
    print "$key => $value</br>\n";
}
```

produces:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class MyClass could not be converted to string...
```

How can I loop through the all the elements of the $class array? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 5):

Your class doesn't implemen the __toString() method, so there's no way for PHP to automatically convert your MyClass to a string when you try to print it:

```
foreach($class as $key => $value) {
                  ^^^^-- odd or even
                          ^^^^^^--- Object of type MyClass

    print "$key => $value</br>\n";
                   ^^^^^^--- try to output object in string context
```

You'd need to add ANOTHER loop to iterate over the class's members:

```
foreach($class as $key => $myclass) {
   foreach($myclass as $key2 => $val) {
       echo ("$key2 => $val");
   }
}
```

... or implement a __toString() method do whatever obj->string conversion you do want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two foreach's

```
class MyClass
{
    public $a;
    public $b;
    function __construct($aX,$bX){
        $this->a = $aX;
        $this->b = $bX;
    }
}

$class = array(
     "odd"=>new MyClass(3,5), 
     "even"=>new MyClass(2,4)
     );
foreach($class as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
            print "$key => $value</br>\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_class_vars](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-class-vars.php):

```
<?php
 class C {
     const CNT = 'Const Value';

     public static $stPubVar = "St Pub Var";
     private static $stPriVar = "St Pri Var";

     public $pubV = "Public Variable 1";
     private $priV = "Private Variable 2";

     public static function g() {
         foreach (get_class_vars(self::class) as $k => $v) {
             echo "$k --- $v\n";
         }
     }
 }

 echo "\n";
 C::g();
```

Result:

```
pubV --- Public Variable 1
priV --- Private Variable 2
stPubVar --- St Pub Var
stPriVar --- St Pri Var
```